# How to trigger mouse hover event in typescript for an element?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I would like to know how to bind/trigger mouse hover event on a particular element in typescript. Here the element will be dynamic based on the keyboard navigation.

For example,
If down arrow key pressed I should be able to activate a row of **ngx data table**.

```
    @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.keyCode = event.keyCode;
    let datatableRow = document.getElementsByClassName("datatable-row-wrapper");

    //Check for Escape key navigation
    if (this.keyCode === 27) {
      // this._rows = [];
      this.searchInputValue = null;
    }
    //Check for Up arrow navigation
    if (this.keyCode === 38) {
      alert("Im Up key!");
      console.log(datatableRow);
      if (datatableRow.length !== 0) {
        console.log("datatable component", this.datatableComponent);
        console.log("Child node", datatableRow[0].childNodes[6]);
      }
    }}
```

Comment: I guess [`@HostListener`](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#respond-to-user-initiated-events) is what you're looking for

Comment: I'm already using @HostListener. but then how do I pass my hover/select event to my ngxdata table row is my problem